# stata Calculating probabilities from a T-distribution

Tags: statistics, stata

My greatest nemesis is understanding the commands of STATA to manipulate the data to solve for each question. I am working with Stata to solve for these sets of question:

Calculating probabilities from a T-distribution. Use the Stata functions “display” “t” “ttail”, “invt” and “invttail” to answer the following questions. For each question, use a T-distribution with degrees of freedom equal to **16**. In your answers, give the full stata command you use, as well as the numerical answer. NOTES: stata’s t(dof,t) function gives lower-tail probabilities for a T-distribution with “dof” degrees of freedom; ttail(dof,t) function gives upper-tail probabilities for a T-distribution with “dof” degrees of freedom. Stata’s invt(dof,p) function gives the value t* for a T-distribution with probability “p” in the lower tail; the function invttail(dof,p) function gives the critical value t* for a T-distribution with “dof” degrees of freedom that has “p” probability in the upper tail. [Hint: it will help to draw in the T distribution and shade in the relevant areas.]

a. Pr [T> 1.6]

b. Pr[T<2.0 or T>2.0]

c. t* such that Pr[T>t*]=0.05

d. t* such that Pr[T<-t* or T>t*]=0.05

e. t* such that Pr[T>t*]= 0.01

f. t* such that Pr[T<-t* or T>t*]=0.01

Answer (score 2):

As this is obviously a homework question I will not give you the answer to each of those points, but instead show you how each of `t(df,t)` and `invt(df,p)` work in Stata, as technically you do not need `ttail` to solve these.

1. The `t(df,x)` command  represents the cumulative Student's t distribution with `df` degrees of freedom and a specified critical value `x`. That is, it will return the probability that a realization of your random variable will be less than or equal to the aforementioned critical value. For example, the probability that a random variable X, following a t distribution with 20 `df`, will be less than or equal to 1.2 is:

```
display t(20,1.2)
.8779192
```

2. The `invt(df,p)` represents the **inverse** cumulative Student's t distribution with `df` degrees of freedom and a specified **probability** `p`. That is, it will return the critical value from your t distribution such that the probability that a realization of that distribution will be les than or equal to that critical value will be exactly p. For example, if we want to know at which value of t* will we have a 15% probability of observing a value less than or equal to t* (again with 20 `df`):

```
disp invt(20, 0.15)
-1.0640158
```

Remember that the t distribution is symmetric, which will occlude the need to use the `ttail` command. Additionally, I find that figuring these problems out in terms of the cumulative distribution will really cement the equal tail properties of the distribution.

Comment: Yes this is definitely a small portion of the dataset I am working through. I would not know how else to ask questions applicable to Stata without applying a work problem to check my answers. In fact you are incorrect about not using ttail at all. Using ttail was a necessity for the first problem. Thank you for the ways to navigate Stata. really appreciate it.

Comment: `ttail(df,x)` is simply `1 - t(df,x)` due to the distribution's symmetry, so you in fact do not need `ttail`. This can be seen by typing the following into the Stata console: `display "ttail is " ttail(20,0.6)  " and (1 - t) is " 1 - t(20,0.6)`

Comment: @AnnaBray Accepting this answer would give you and JR96 some reputation, and recognition for their help to you.  FYI, questions without any attempt at code whatsoever are likely to get downvoted.